# 'Fill an appeal' or 'file an appeal'?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

I encountered both expressions but I am not sure which is correct.

Should I use "fill an appeal" or "file an appeal"?

Comment: Neither is an idiom. What does your dictionary tell you?

Comment: @coleopterist: [file an appeal](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22file+an+appeal%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is standard terminology, where *file* effectively means *place on file* (i.e. - go through the standard bureaucratic procedures to **lodge** an appeal, thereby recorded **on file** with the relevant authorities). General Reference.

Comment: *Fill an appeal* looks like a typo. Have you seen it more than once?

Comment: @Anixx: You might **fill out** an application form to initiate your appeal, but you don't actually fill the appeal itself.

Comment: @bib Phrases like '*fill an appeal*' are not a typos. It's an error repeated so often that it's almost a regionalism in some places. Similar 'errors' can be seen in plenty in 'Indian English', for instance: 'Did you *fill* your tax returns?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "File an appeal" since you are issuing a challenge to someone or something and that will go through an entire formal process and then be documented for reference, hence the "file".

You "Fill something" when you have to simply enter some data for some process or application which may or may not be referenced in the future once the application has been processed.

Comment: I have no idea what you're getting at with that definition of "Fill something".

Comment: Hey, answer edited. Thanks for pointing it out, realized it didn't make much sense myself.

Answer (score 2):

If for e.g. you want to lodge a complaint or you want to write to the university to check your exam papers once again, then you 'file an appeal'.

I dont know how you fill an appeal.